# Remove spacing of label in specified design sample

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have following design:

[image]

Code for it:

```
   <table width="70%" align="center" class ="TableBorder">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="Heading" align="center">
                    Add Client
                </td>
            </tr>

           <tr>
                <td class="NormalText" align="right">
                    Client Name:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientName" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName0" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="NormalText" width="40%" align="right">
                    Client Login Email ID:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientID" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName1" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="NormalText" align="right">
                    Client Password:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientPwd" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName2" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="NormalText">
                    Contact No.:</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactNo" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName3" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="NormalText" valign="top"  >
                    Address:</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox" 
                        Height="100px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName4" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="NormalText" width="30%">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonColor" Text="Save" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonColor" 
                        Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I just wanted to remove spacing between marked area of Address textbox and "*" label.

I tried to give property as valign="top" to label, but its not accepting it.

Please help me.

Comment: You'll probably need to move the labels to their own cells so the text box cells aren't expanded. Or valign="top" on your cells might work.

Comment: nope, i added extra <td> for label besides address textbox and it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
<table width="70%" align="center" class="TableBorder">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="Heading" align="center">
                    Add Client
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="NormalText" align="right">
                    Client Name:
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientName" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName0" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="NormalText" width="40%" align="right">
                    Client Login Email ID:
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientID" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName1" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="NormalText" align="right">
                    Client Password:
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientPwd" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName2" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="NormalText">
                    Contact No.:
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactNo" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName3" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="NormalText" valign="top">
                    Address:
                </td>
                <td align="left" class="style1" valign="top">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox" Height="100px"
                        TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName4" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="NormalText" width="30%">                    
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonColor" Text="Save" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonColor" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: yup, that extra <td> for lable over there worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this

add **style="vertical-align:top;"** to label

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAgentName4" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*" style="vertical-align:top;"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use text **vertical-align: text-top;** in your css for td like this:

```
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: text-top;">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox" 
               Height="100px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Label ID="lblAgentName4" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="*"></asp:Label>
</td>
```

Because your asp renders your Label control to html **span** element, and for spans need text-top style/